# Java Unit testing path matching

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am trying to understand Unit testing and how the correct classes are being fetched on test time,
I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what is going on behind the scenes and how safe/correct my usages for this are.

This is a very simple example of what i am trying to do, i wrote it here inline so it probably contains some errors, please try to ignore them, as stupid as they may be.

A very simple project directory:

`ba/src/main/java/utils/BaUtils.java
ba/test/main/java/utils/BaUtilsTest.java
notBa/src/main/java/im/BaObj.java`

BaUtils.java code:

```
package com.ba.utils;
import notBa.im.BaObj;
public class BaUtils{
    public String doSomething(BaObj obj){
        obj.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I would like to test BaUtils wihtout actually calling doSomething, and i can't change anything on `BaObj` class or `notBa` package. I know that i can (by 'can' i mean it will work) add a new java file to 'ba' project (`ba/test/java/notBa/main/java/im/BaObj.java`) that will have the same package as the original BaObj, and at runtime the test will import this one instead of the real one, so `BaUtils` code is tested but `BaObj` code is not excecuted.
that should look something like like :

```
package notBa.im.Baobj
public class BaObj{
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Did something");
    }
}
```

My questions are (And thank you for reaching this far):

How does this work (Reading references would be great).
Is this kind of test building considered 'good' or 'safe' ?

Thanks!

Comment: what will you do if some code is changed in BaUtils.java?

Comment: BaUtils.java is the code i would like to test, if it changes it should break the test - which means the test did it work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use a mocking framework (I for myself like Mockito).

The test would look like this:

```
class BlaUtilTes{
  @Rule
  public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

  @Mock
  Blaobj blaobj;

  @Test
  public void doSomething_WithMockedBlaobj_callsDosomethingOnBlaobj(){
    // arrange
    BlaUtil blaUtil= new BlaUtil();
    // act
    blaUtil.doSomething(blaobj);
    // assert
    Mockito.verify(blaobj).doSomething();
  }
}
```

find more information here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#testing-with-mock-objects

Answer (score 1):

Your BaUtilsTest class should look like this.. I have used mockito for for mocking external dependencies. Also I changed the method return type to String for easy understanding.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class BaUtilsTest {

    BaUtils util;

    @Mock
    BaObj mockBaObj;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        util = new BaUtils();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {

        Mockito.when(mockBaObj.doSomething()).thenReturn("did the work using mock");

        String result = util.doSomething(mockBaObj);

        Assert.assertEquals("did the work using mock", result);
    }
}
```